# Get week from selected monthcalendar-date

Tags: c#, week-number, monthcalendar

I need a solution to calculate the week from the selected date. (in monthcalendar)
I tried:

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Year, 
                            monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Month, 
                            monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Day);

DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Year, 
                            1, 
                            1);

System.TimeSpan varTime = dt1 - dt2;
int weeks = (varTime.Days / 7) + 1;
```

But start and enddays of a weeks are not correct and in some years I got 53 weeks?
what is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Some years have 53 weeks, that's not an error that's by "design"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int WeekNumber(DateTime date)
{
    CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    int weekNum = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date,
                                          CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,
                                          DayOfWeek.Monday);
    return weekNum;
}
```

Remember to correct the CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday to your current culture, the one use here is for danish/denmark

Answer (score 0):

Try the GetWeekOfYear function of calendar. look here and scroll down for full example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx

Comment: Anybody posted the solution and delete it again.
Anyway, I could grab the snipped. Thank you *unknown* :)

Comment: @user1559441: I have undeleted my answer again - just realized that i wasn't actually answer all of your question :-)